# Efficient way to get group names in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, processing-efficiency

I have a .csv file with around 300,000 rows. I have set it to group by a particular column, with each group having around 140 members (2138 total groups).

I am trying to generate a numpy array of the group names. I have used a for loop to generate the names as of now but it takes a while for everything to process.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv')
grouped = df.groupby('col1')
group_names = []
for name,group in grouped: group_names.append(name)
group_names = np.array(group_names, dtype=object)
```

I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this, whether by using a pandas module or directly converting the names into a numpy array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fastest way would most likely be just to use `unique` on the column you are grouping by, which gives you all unique values. The output will be an array of your group names.

```
group_names = df.col1.unique()
```

Answer (score 11):

`groupby` objects have a [`.groups`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.groups.html#pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.groups) attribute:

```
groups = df.groupby('col1').groups
```

this returns a dict of the group name->labels

example:

```
In[257]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':list('aabcccc'), 'b':np.random.randn(7)})
groups = df.groupby('a').groups
groups

Out[257]: 
{'a': Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64'),
 'b': Int64Index([2], dtype='int64'),
 'c': Int64Index([3, 4, 5, 6], dtype='int64')}

groups.keys()
Out[258]: dict_keys(['a', 'b', 'c'])
```

Comment: is the dict guaranteed to be ordered the same way as iterating?

Comment: When I have a df with few groups that have a lot of members, `df.groupby(*args)` takes 4ms for me, while `df.groupby(*args).groups` takes 240ms. Is this because the first expression doesn't actually separate out the groups yet? If not, and if you're only interested in the group names (the keys of the dict), might there be something that only returns the names and skips returning the indices of each group? @sacuL 's answer is much faster, but it only works if you want to group by a single column.