# How to title matplotlib subplots as part of for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, subplot

I am having some trouble trying to figure out how to title matplotlib subplots as part of a for loop, and am not sure how to use a referenced value as part of the title. I am using python.

I have the following dataframe:

```
Parameter   P1      P2     P3       P1      P2     P3      P1      P2     P3
Color       Blue    Red    Green    Blue    Red    Green   Blue    Red    Green
Size
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Small    XX      XX     XX       XX      XX     XX      XX      XX     XX
  Medium    XX      XX     XX       XX      XX     XX      XX      XX     XX
     Big    XX      XX     XX       XX      XX     XX      XX      XX     XX
```

Then running the following code:

```
fig, axs = plt.subplots(nrows=1, 
                        ncols=5, 
                        figsize=(10, 3))

groups = df.groupby(level=1, axis=1)

for ax, group in zip(axs.flatten(), groups):
    group[1].plot(kind='bar', 
                  ax=ax,
                  color=['b', 'g', 'r'],
                  sharey=True,
                  legend=False,
                  rot=True)
```

I get three bar graphs, as I want. The only problem is that they are not titled. These 3 bar graphs are supposed to correspond to P1, P2, and P3. How can I title these subplots as part of the for loop so that they are titled "Parameter 1", "Parameter 2", and "Parameter 3"? I am very confused about how to enter a subplot title function in the for loop that references I prior order string.

The imports I used are:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Comment: `ax.set_title()` is how you would add it in basic Matplotlib. Pandas may also have a way to add a title directly in the `plot` call.

Comment: ... also please consider adding your imports and how you created `df`.  I'm just assuming that is a pandas data frame, but...

Comment: yes it is a pandas dataframe. I just updated my post with the imports I used.

Comment: ... and did you try `ax.set_title`?

Comment: Yes I tried `ax.set_title('Parameter_X')` in the first line of the for loop, indented right underneath: `for ax, group in zip(axs.flatten(), groups):`, but this gave the same "Parameter_X" title for each subplot. I want that "X" to be based on the Parameter number, whether P1, P2, or P3, but I am not sure how to access that within the groups.

Comment: My ignorance of pandas is vast, however, google says: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50859987/efficient-way-to-get-group-names-in-pandas

Comment: To `group[1].plot(...)`, add `title=group[0]` you must. See section **3.** of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68793513/7758804).